# What is the easiest way to install OpenVAS omblib with Python?

Tags: python, installation, openvas

I have followed https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openvas.omplib#installing-openvas-omplib with no luck. Below is the code they suggest (I used):

```
from openvas.omplib import *
manager = openvas.omplib.OMPClient(host = sensor)
manager.open(USER,PASSWORD)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
manager = openvas.omplib.OMPClient(host=sensor)
NameError: name = 'openvas' is not defined
```

It seems the library is not installing correctly or all the way. To install, I ran:

```
easy_install openvas.omplib
```

Any ideas?

I have also tried Openvas_lib 1.0 (another form). This one also runs into errors. (yes I have the variables set to something)

```
from openvas_lib import VulnscanManager, VulnscanException
scan = VulnscanManager("localhost",USER,PASSWORD,9392)
scan.launch_scan(target,profile="empty")
```

[Here is an image of my errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PbwK.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned openvas_lib installed correctly, but it comes with the errors in the image. Openvas.omplib doesn't have a way to install via pip. Unless you know how to?

Answer (score 0):

It seems openvas wasn't updated for Kali 2.0 yet. However, openvas_lib works perfectly on Kali's older version. Hopefully they update openvas_lib for the newer version of kali soon.